# Qt Widget inside qt3d window

Tags: c++, qt, qt3d

How to put a label or button into qt3d window? Is it possible? Havent seen any example... I was trying to simply put qt3d in windowcontainer, assign layout to it and layout->addWiget() but it just doesnt work.

Comment: Did you have a look at the [planets example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qt3d-planets-qml-example.html). It's not directly `QWidgets` but could get you started.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this is a farily old question but I wanted to give a more detailed answer if anyone else stumbles across this.

1. I implemented a Qt3D widget which you can find [here](https://github.com/florianblume/qt3d-widget). Unfortunately it relies on a method to obtain the texture id from `QAbstractTexture` which is only available from Qt >= 5.13 so that's the minimum version you have to use.
2. `createWindowContainer` draws the respective window above everything else. So you'll never be able to draw any buttons inside the container.
3. You can of course have buttons and everything else **around** your containered 3D window. But that's specifically not what you wanted.
4. You can use [Dear ImGui](https://github.com/ocornut/imgui) - and it's [Qt3D integration](https://github.com/alpqr/imgui-qt3d). ImGui is used to draw GUI elements using vertices in 3D environments.
5. Of course you can always use QML - there you should be able to place buttons inside the 3D view.

Answer (score 0):

you have both label and (radio)buttons on the first example for C++ into the QT3d documentation, refer to [Qt 3D: Basic Shapes C++ Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qt3d-basicshapes-cpp-example.html)

*QExtrudedTextGeometry* seems to be the class for 3D text

Comment: I want to add label inside 3d view, not outside.

Comment: @KamilSłotwiński look at _QExtrudedTextGeometry_, seems the class for 3D text